# BitNami DjangoStack not 'self contained', cannot run application

Tags: python, django, windows-7, bitnami

I installed the Windows (32bit) BitNami DjangoStack 1.4.1.0 and elected not to install the python that came with it as I already have Python 2.7 installed.

I got the error below and also an internal server error when I clicked on the button in the introduction web page (so Appache is running ok)

```
enter code here
[error] mod_wsgi (pid=3990): Target WSGI script '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/scripts/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module
```

I found a similar question but that related to installing on Amazon. Also following through the answers it appeared that the problem is that the wsgi had been compiled against the wrong python version.

I then uninstalled BitNami and re-installed using the python version that was provided - still the same message.

I don't see how the wrong python version can be the problem if the BitNami package is self contained, i.e. comes with all the bits needed to run.

In case my previously installed version was causing the problem I remove it from the PATH environment variable.

Also the documentation for Windows seems wrong. django.conf and django.wsgi are not where the docs say they are (\Users\user\BitNami SDjangoStack projects\apps). In fact the only thing in that directory is the new project I selected on installation - no apps directory. I found the files in the BitNami directories.

Also when I typed python in the BitNami console I got python 2.7.3, not 2.7.2 which is listed in the installation guide.

I thought this package would be wonderful to help me get a production Django site running. It is now ready in the development phase to go live for testing.

Comment: Consider not using an Apache-based stack, but a combination of *nginx* and *uwsgi*.

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean with not installing Python? BitNami DjangoStack is self contained in the sense that it includes its own Python and its dependecies. Also you mentioned that you are running it on Windows but the path /opt/bitnami is the default path when installing as root in Linux. What exact options did you select during the installation?